# Parameter -NP with a MPI_Comm_spawn

Tags: c, mpi

I was writing a code to understand **MPI_Comm_spawn**. I found some examples in the Internet, all compiled and executed with sucess but when I put the follow statement: mpirun -np 2 ./program I received a error. So, **MPI_Comm_spawn** only work with one process (-np 1)?

mpirun -np 1 ./executable - ok

mpirun -np 2 ./executable - don't run with values greater than one

I use the following code:

[code used](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/mpi-standard/mpi-report-2.0/node98.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely spawn processes when you have more than 1 process. That example is just designed to only work with one process. [Here](http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/mpi_comm_spawn.html) is an example of some code that will work with more than 1 process.

Comment: Someone can explain why even when I set the number of process to more than 10 only two process child are created in the code above? mpirun -np 10 ./spawn_example